# Transform nested array into new dimension

Tags: julia

Given an array as follows:

```
A = Array{Array{Int}}(2,2)
A[1,1] = [1,2]
A[1,2] = [3,4]
A[2,1] = [5,6]
A[2,2] = [7,8]
```

We then have that `A` is a 2x2 array with elements of type `Array{Int}`:

```
2×2 Array{Array{Int64,N} where N,2}:
 [1, 2]  [3, 4]
 [5, 6]  [7, 8]
```

It is possible to access the entries with e.g. `A[1,2]` but `A[1,2,2]` would not work since the third dimension is not present in A. However, `A[1,2][2]` works, since `A[1,2]` returns an array of length 2.

The question is then, what is a nice way to convert `A` into a 3-dimensional array, `B`, so that `B[i,j,k]` refers the the i,j-th array and the k-th element in that array. E.g. `B[2,1,2] = 6`.

There is a straightforward way to do this using 3 nested loops and reconstructing the array, element-by-element, but I'm hoping there is a nicer construction. (Some application of `cat` perhaps?)

Comment: `cat(3,first.(A),last.(A))` also gives the same matrix. If more than two elements in internal vectors, `getindex` can be used to generalize this construction.

Comment: I figured out one way:  `B = permutedims(reshape(collect(Iterators.flatten(A)), (2,2,2)), [3,2,1])`, but it is very badly readable and I'd rather use the generators from @durand's answer below.
To generalise your answer: `cat(3, map(idx -> getindex.(A, idx),(1:2))...)` may be alright (for suitable ranges).

Comment: The expressions in your comment can also be written: `permutedims(reshape(vcat(A...),2,2,2),[2,3,1])` and `cat(3,(getindex.(A,i) for i=1:2)...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to Dan Getz's comments, I think the following works well *and* is succinct:

```
cat(3,(getindex.(A,i) for i=1:2)...)
```

where `2` is the length of the nested array. It would also work for higher dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a 3-d array from A using an array comprehension

```
julia> B = [ A[i,j][k] for i=1:2, j=:1:2, k=1:2 ]
2×2×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  3
 5  7

[:, :, 2] =
 2  4
 6  8

julia> B[2,1,2]
6
```

However a more general solution would be to overload the getindex function for arrays with the same type of A. This is more efficient since there is no need to copy the original data.

```
julia> import Base.getindex

julia> getindex(A::Array{Array{Int}}, i::Int, j::Int, k::Int) = A[i,j][k]
getindex (generic function with 179 methods)

julia> A[2,1,2]
6
```

Answer (score 0):

`permutedims(reshape(collect(Base.Iterators.flatten(A)), (2,2,2)), (2,3,1))`

also does the job and appears to be faster than the accepted `cat()` answer for me.

EDIT: I'm sorry, I just saw that this has already been suggested in the comments.